# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found IIS 7.5

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, wcf, iis-7.5

I have an WCF web service that I was able to call from an Android application in Visual Studio IIS server, but now after publishing the service in my local IIS server when I try to make a call from the application I receive the following error as response:
"HTTP Error 404.0 - The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
**The ISAPI and CGI restrictions are all allowed**
**Calling the service from the URL in browser works normally**
This is the first time that I try to make a service publication, any help will be welcome.

My web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="VendasEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=SERVER IP;User Id=user;password=pass;Persist Security Info=True;database=database&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="httpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">          
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>          
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="FreedomVendasService.VendasService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="httpBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="FreedomVendasService.IVendasService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <host>    
    <baseAddresses>      
      <add baseAddress = "http://localhost/VendasService" />
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem adding [ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)] above the service implementation class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing any Host element in the web.config like

```
<host>
    <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress = "http://localhost/service1" />
    </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

Can you show me your web.config file.

Comment: Now, I'm receiving this message: "It's not possible to read the 'host' configuration because a section declaration is missing"

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck this in Windows Explorer.

"Hide file type extensions for known types"